# Android M : How to build and link your own jar within AOSP?

Tags: android

I want to add my own jar into the AOSP. For that I have created `Android.mk` make file with the command `include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)`. I have also added the library name under `build/target/product/core_minimal.mk` (Product_boot_Jar section).

My issue: With the `mm` command I can see the jar under `system/framework/myOwn.jar` (Built successfully). But with complete make command it is unable to copy `myown.jar` into `/system/framework`.

Any idea on why it is not working within Android M?